# Setting up MongoDB database to allow for transactions

Tags: mongodb

I have a database on which I want to perform a large number of update queries on a collection at a time.

If at least one of those queries fails I would like to be able to undo my changes to the database so that it looks identical to what it did before I began running the changes.

As I was reading I ran into the concept of transactions. To my understanding, this would allow me to carry out the updates as one transaction. If any of them fails I can then abort the transaction which would stop the changes from going into my database.

First question. Am I correct in saying that using transactions is the right approach in this case assuming at most one person modifies the database at a time?

Second question, how do I achieve the setup that does what I want? I read that this involves setting up a replica set. I am working off of one computer and for the time being would like to keep it that way. Any links that show me how to do this step-by-step would be appreciated, all I seem to find are pages that show arrows between primary and secondary nodes and attempt to explain it at a conceptual level.

Comment: There is the [Transaction API](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/) but you could maybe just use a seperate collection.

Answer (score 0):

Transactions are one way of grouping operations. There are other ways of achieving various requirements that do not involve transactions (MongoDB only added multi-document transactions in version 4, there have been numerous previous releases that were used in all kinds of settings successfully).

> at most one person modifies the database at a time

This is one way to think about the problem. A different way of thinking is, *assuming* there are concurrent updates, how does one, obtain a *consistent* set of data. This sort of thinking generally works better for real-life systems (if a website has 100,000 or a million users, trying to do one thing at a time will probably not work).

> I read that this involves setting up a replica set.

You need  a replica set or a sharded cluster for transactions. But you can set up a single-node replica set for development - this is done following the same [instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/) but you only set up one node.